# How to add action to UIAlertView in Swift (iOS 7)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add an action to the Retry button, but when the user presses the Retry button nothing happens.

```
var createAccountErrorAlert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()

createAccountErrorAlert.delegate = self                

createAccountErrorAlert.title = "Oops"
createAccountErrorAlert.message = "Could not create account!"
createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Dismiss")
createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Retry")

createAccountErrorAlert.show()
```

Function for determining index of button pressed?

```
func alertView(View: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){

    switch buttonIndex{

    case 1:
        createAccount()

    default:
        //Some code here..

    }
}
```

Comment: How have you tried to debug this? Have you put a breakpoint inside the function to see if it fires? Have you put a log statement in to see what `buttonIndex` is? These are the first things I'd need to do to replicate the error you're having.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I tested your code and it is working fine for me it prints the respective result:

```
func showAlert(){
    var createAccountErrorAlert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()

    createAccountErrorAlert.delegate = self

    createAccountErrorAlert.title = "Oops"
    createAccountErrorAlert.message = "Could not create account!"
    createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Dismiss")
    createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Retry")

    createAccountErrorAlert.show()
}

func alertView(View: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){

    switch buttonIndex{

    case 1:
        NSLog("Retry");
    break;
    case 0:
        NSLog("Dismiss");
        break;
    default:
        NSLog("Default");
        break;
        //Some code here..

    }
}
```

It print dismiss when i click on dismiss button.

Comment: For those who may have a problem : it doesn't work if you use "var createAccountErrorAlert= UIAlertView()"

Answer (score 0):

That's because the index of your retry button is 1, not 0. The dismiss button has index 0.

If you put the following code in a playground, you will actually see the indexes of the buttons (as documented on the addButtonWithTitle method):

```
var createAccountErrorAlert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
createAccountErrorAlert.title = "Oops"
createAccountErrorAlert.message = "Could not create account!"
createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Dismiss") //Prints 0
createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Retry") //Prints 1
```

Comment: It does when I try your code. Could you also send the code within your createAccount() method? Or just try what @wjl suggested, placing a breakpoint in the delegate method, and checking the index value. Or put a "println(buttonIndex)" within the delegate method and see what is printed on the console when you hit the retry button.

Answer (score 0):

Index is wrong. The following (based on iOS single view default app template) works for me (where I wired a button to trigger `@IBAction buttonPressed`). Don't forget to make your view controller a `UIAlertViewDelegate` (though the following works without doing so):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender : AnyObject) {
        var createAccountErrorAlert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()

        createAccountErrorAlert.delegate = self

        createAccountErrorAlert.title = "Oops"
        createAccountErrorAlert.message = "Could not create account!"
        createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Dismiss")
        createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Retry")

        createAccountErrorAlert.show()
    }

    func alertView(View: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {

        switch buttonIndex {

        default:
            println("alertView \(buttonIndex) clicked")

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres the way I did it, with shorter lines of code:

```
func showAlert(){
    var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Choose", message: "Which_pill", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle:"Red")
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Blue")
    alert.show()
}

func alertView(View: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){
    switch buttonIndex{
    case 1: println("Blue")
    case 0: println("Red")
    default: println("Is this part even possible?")
    }
}
```